# Highchart Funnel Chart not showing

Tags: php, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am developing application that uses highchart as charting framework.i have uses 8 to 9 type of chart and all of them run successfully but in funnel chart i failed. highchart is quite simple but have not any idea about this problem.

i have also look at highchart api but my method is different those charts.
here is link of code

thanks in advance

Comment: here is link http://jsfiddle.net/L7f8f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your fiddle. You haven't created a chart object. instead of the below:

```
var currud = {
   ........
 }
```

you can create a new chart object via `new Highcharts.Chart`.

```
var currud = new Highcharts.Chart({
 ........
});
```

You can see your fiddles working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Un7/2/)